# number formatting in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to format numbers like following

```
13.20 to 13.2
13.34 to 13.34
13.00 to 13
```

I have tried to use a combination of str_replace() and number_format() but not able to produce required result.

Please help me, if anyone have any idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check 0's at the end and remove it, also if '.' is at the end also remove it.

Comment: What should happen to `13.12345`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the built-in round function:

```
echo round(1.23456, 2);
```

This will return 1.23. Of course, you have to decide how many numbers after the decimal point to keep.

Comment: This produces the result OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

`number_format` should work:

```
<?php
    $number = 12.345;
    echo number_format($number, 1); # Produces number with one decimal precision.
?>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
    $number = 12.30;

    #Strips ZEROs and decimal point from the end
    echo rtrim($number, '0.'); #Result: 12.3
?>
```

Comment: he just want to remove '0' appended at the end in the result I guess. as he kept 13.34 as it is

Comment: i want one decimal place only if the values after decimal points are like .30, .20 if values are like .34 .55 i want two decimal points

Comment: what will happen in case number is 12.34?? output will be 12.3

Comment: Added another solution - it will strip `0` and `.` from the right. `13.45` => `13.45`, `13.40` => `13.4` and `13.00` => `13`

Comment: @NaN see Vincent Decaux's Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Or just simply, this is magic :

```
$number + 0

// 12.30 + 0 = 12.3
```

Or you can cast your number to float :

```
echo floatval($number);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of variable you're using. A string `13.20` will output `13.20` but a **float** `13.20` will output `13.2`.

All you have to do is cast it:

```
echo (float) '13.20'; // Will output 13.2
```